# Not Able to Update Android Studio 1.5 to latest Android Studio 2.0 beta version

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.5 how i can update to beta version of android studio 2.0, when i am trying to update its showing "**You Already have the latest version of Android Studio installed**".

[image]

I want to update my Android Studio but i don't know how I can do this.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Click the blue "Updates" text

[image]

Change the "Automatically check updates for" to "Beta Channel" then click "OK"

[image]

And then reclick [Help]=>[Check for update...], you'll see

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on settings

[image]

2. Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates

[image]

3. Change update channel to beta. (Only the first one)

[image]

4. Check for updates.